# Como detectar usuarios sin ID y eliminarlos de Google sheet

Tags: php, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo el siguiente codigo en un codigo PHP en mi contactform.php el cual lo que hace es coger los datos e insertarlos en un google sheet.

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['nombre'])) {
$dataAgregar = array('gclid' => $_SESSION['gclid'],
'nombre' => $_SESSION['nombre'],
'email' => $_SESSION['email'],
'telefono' =>"'" .$_SESSION['phone'],
 'mensaje' => $_SESSION['mensaje'],
 'landing' =>  $landingP
 );
 $listFeed->insert($dataAgregar);
}
if(!empty($_SESSION['nombre2'])) {
  $dataAgregar2 = array('gclid' => $_SESSION['gclid2'],
'nombre' => $_SESSION['nombre2'],
 'email' => $_SESSION['email2'],
 'telefono' =>"'" .$_SESSION['phone2'],
 'mensaje' => $_SESSION['mensaje2'],
 'landing' =>  $landingP2
 );
 $listFeed->insert($dataAgregar2);
}
```

lo que quiero hacer es que si no hay gclid no lo inserte en el google sheet, he pensado en realizar el siguiente codigo para realizar dicha funcion.

```
if(empty($_SESSION['gclid'])){}
if(empty($_SESSION['gclid2'])){}/*Es porque tengo dos gclid*/
if(!empty($_SESSION['nombre'])) {
$dataAgregar = array('gclid' => $_SESSION['gclid'],
'nombre' => $_SESSION['nombre'],
'email' => $_SESSION['email'],
'telefono' =>"'" .$_SESSION['phone'],
 'mensaje' => $_SESSION['mensaje'],
 'landing' =>  $landingP
 );
 $listFeed->insert($dataAgregar);
}
if(!empty($_SESSION['nombre2'])) {
  $dataAgregar2 = array('gclid' => $_SESSION['gclid2'],
'nombre' => $_SESSION['nombre2'],
 'email' => $_SESSION['email2'],
 'telefono' =>"'" .$_SESSION['phone2'],
 'mensaje' => $_SESSION['mensaje2'],
 'landing' =>  $landingP2
 );
 $listFeed->insert($dataAgregar2);
}
```

Estaría bien asi el codigo para hacer lo que quiero hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías comprobar de una vez las dos variables si están vacías:

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['gclid'] && !empty($_SESSION['nombre'])) { 
// Tú código 
}
```

Comment: Pero el !empty es para saber si no esta vacio no? Lo entiendo si no esta vacio lo haces si esta vacio no hagas nada verdad?

Comment: Correcto... la condición `if` se puede traducir de esta forma: `Si no esta vacío 'gclid' Y no esta vacío 'nombre'....`

Comment: puedes jugar [aquí](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d7ead2f9855d1452625cb55434a0429f271540f5) en el ejemplo que te he dejado

Comment: Gracias por la solución